# Нужна ли запятая между "семьи" и "могут"? Почему? Заранее спасибо

Tags: пунктуация

Только связь со взрослым человеком, доверительные отношения и ощущение себя частью семьи могут помочь однажды брошенному ребёнку.

Answer (score 1):

*Только связь со взрослым человеком, доверительные отношения и ощущение себя частью семьи могут помочь однажды брошенному ребёнку.*

Запятые ставятся **между однородными членами, а не после них**.  Между подлежащим и сказуемым запятая не ставится, если нет обособленных членов или придаточных предложений, а здесь их нет.